# Using JavaScript to render HTML; nothing appearing but values will alert

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm taking some information from some variables I have already defined outside this function to create a html svg text box.

Here is the function which is causing me trouble:

```
 RenderTextBox:function()
{
  alert('this.x: ' + this.x);
  alert('this.y: ' + this.y);
  this.textBox = paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.htmlTextBox);
 }
```

The alerts works prefectly, and prompt me with the values expected. However, the final line which is supposed to create the text box puts them nowhere to be seen. Does anybody know why?

If I replace '`this.x, this.y..`' with numerical  values in the final line of the function, the text box is placed correctly. It's only when I use the 'this.x' and 'this.y' that I have issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes numerical values are converted in strings. That's one of the very bad point about javascript : variables are not needed to be typed.

You should try to parse them as int in order to make them react as integers again : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Comment: +1, but also follow Doug Crockford's advice and always include the radix (10 if you're working in base-10).

Answer (score 0):

Wild Guess: an you try putting `this.x` and `this.y` into variables and then passing these variables to the function call in the last line?

Something like:

```
var tx = this.x;
var ty = this.y;
this.textBox = paper.text(tx, ty, this.htmlTextBox);
```

Comment: that is equivalent to the OP's snippet.